# Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.Client Exception. timezone region not found

Tags: .net, amazon-ec2, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, upgrade, oracle.manageddataaccess

I am working on upgrading .Net 4.6 project to .Net 4.8 and as part of upgrade there were lot of packages that were upgraded  including Oracle packages

```
    <Reference Include="Oracle.ManagedDataAccess, Version=4.122.19.1, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=89b483f429c47342, processorArchitecture=MSIL">
      <HintPath>..\packages\Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.19.8.0\lib\net40\Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.dll</HintPath>
    </Reference>
    <Reference Include="Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.EntityFramework, Version=6.122.19.1, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=89b483f429c47342, processorArchitecture=MSIL">
      <HintPath>..\packages\Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.EntityFramework.19.7.0\lib\net45\Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.EntityFramework.dll</HintPath>
    </Reference>
```

to,

```
    <Reference Include="Oracle.ManagedDataAccess, Version=4.122.21.1, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=89b483f429c47342, processorArchitecture=MSIL">
      <HintPath>..\packages\Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.21.11.0\lib\net462\Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.dll</HintPath>
    </Reference>
    <Reference Include="Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.EntityFramework, Version=6.122.21.1, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=89b483f429c47342, processorArchitecture=MSIL">
      <HintPath>..\packages\Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.EntityFramework.21.9.0\lib\net462\Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.EntityFramework.dll</HintPath>
    </Reference>
```

Binding redirects were also maintained as needed.

**Now the upgrade works locally and I am able to fetch all the data,
But when the project is deployed to AWS EC2 Instance, this causes very peculiar error.**

```
"Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.Client.OracleException (0x80004005): ORA-00604: error occurred at recursive SQL level 1\nORA-01882: timezone region not found\r\n   at OracleInternal.ConnectionPool.PoolManager`3.Get(ConnectionString csWithDiffOrNewPwd, Boolean bGetForApp, OracleConnection connRefForCriteria, String affinityInstanceName, Boolean bForceMatch)\r\n   at OracleInternal.ConnectionPool.OraclePoolManager.Get(ConnectionString csWithNewPassword, Boolean bGetForApp, OracleConnection connRefForCriteria, String affinityInstanceName, Boolean bForceMatch)\r\n   at OracleInternal.ConnectionPool.OracleConnectionDispenser`3.Get(ConnectionString cs, PM conPM, ConnectionString pmCS, SecureString securedPassword, SecureString securedProxyPassword, OracleConnection connRefForCriteria)\r\n   at Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.Client.OracleConnection.Open()\r\n
```

Can anybody help me in this ? Fix should be less hacky and more stable and replicable .

I do not know how to fix this issue.

I saw lot of online resource, they seem to indicate adding environment varialbe on EC2 Instance,I doubt that could be real fix as this was never needed in earlier versions.

Also, some resource seem to point that Oracle package version and DB version might be an issue.

But I do not know how to really fix this issue.